# Why is Google's ML Face Detection Kit crashing on .process()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-mlkit

I am creating a face detector app which will detect faces in real time and identify landmarks on faces. The landmarks for the faces are working perfectly fine, however my real time face detection isn't working at all.

I followed the instructions in Google's ML Kit(https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android), but am really struggling to obtain the functionality in real time face detection.

In my debugger, the code crashes at `facedetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener()` and instead goes into the `onFailure()`

This is my code for the realtime face detection part(I have commented some parts + reduced redundancy).

```
@Override
    //process method to detect frame by frame in real time face detection
    public void process(@NonNull Frame frame) {
        int width = frame.getSize().getWidth();
        int height = frame.getSize().getHeight();


        InputImage image = InputImage.fromByteArray(
                frame.getData(),
                /* image width */width,
                /* image height */height,
                 //if camera is facing front rotate image 90, else 270 degrees
                (cameraFacing != Facing.FRONT) ? 90 : 270,
                InputImage.IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888 // or IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12
        );

        FaceDetectorOptions faceDetectorOptions = new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                //setting contour mode to detect all facial contours in real time
                .build();

        FaceDetector faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(faceDetectorOptions);
        faceDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Face> faces) {

                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                Paint dotPaint = new Paint();
                dotPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                dotPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                dotPaint.setStrokeWidth(6f);

                Paint linePaint = new Paint();
                linePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                linePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
                //looping through each face to detect each contour
                for (Face face : faces) {


                    List<PointF> faceContours = face.getContour(
                            FaceContour.FACE
                    ).getPoints();

                    for (int i = 0; i < faceContours.size(); i++) {
                        PointF faceContour = null;
                        if (i != (faceContours.size() - 1)) {
                            faceContour = faceContours.get(i);
                            canvas.drawLine(
                                    faceContour.x, faceContour.y, faceContours.get(i + 1).x, faceContours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint
                            );
                        } else {//if at the last point, draw to the first point
                            canvas.drawLine(faceContour.x, faceContour.y, faceContours.get(0).x, faceContours.get(0).y, linePaint);
                        }
                        canvas.drawCircle(faceContour.x, faceContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);
                    }//end inner loop


                    List<PointF> leftEyebrowTopCountours = face.getContour(
                            FaceContour.LEFT_EYEBROW_TOP).getPoints();
                    for (int i = 0; i < leftEyebrowTopCountours.size(); i++) {
                        PointF leftEyebrowTopContour = leftEyebrowTopCountours.get(i);
                        if (i != (leftEyebrowTopCountours.size() - 1))
                            canvas.drawLine(leftEyebrowTopContour.x, leftEyebrowTopContour.y, leftEyebrowTopCountours.get(i + 1).x, leftEyebrowTopCountours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                        canvas.drawCircle(leftEyebrowTopContour.x, leftEyebrowTopContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                    }
                }
              }
```

Side note: I am using Pixel 2 API 29 in my emulator. I left out the repetitive code since I am just going through contours

Full code for reference:

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceContour;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetection;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetector;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetectorOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceLandmark;
import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView;
import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.controls.Facing;
import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.frame.Frame;
import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.frame.FrameProcessor;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FrameProcessor {
    private Facing cameraFacing = Facing.FRONT;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private CameraView faceDetectionCameraView;
    private RecyclerView bottomSheetRecyclerView;
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    private ArrayList<FaceDetectionModel> faceDetectionModels;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        faceDetectionModels = new ArrayList<>();
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet));

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.face_detection_image_view);
        faceDetectionCameraView = findViewById(R.id.face_detection_camera_view);

        Button toggle = findViewById(R.id.face_detection_cam_toggle_button);
        FrameLayout bottomSheetButton = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_button);
        bottomSheetRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_recycler_view);

        faceDetectionCameraView.setFacing(cameraFacing);
        faceDetectionCameraView.setLifecycleOwner(MainActivity.this);
        faceDetectionCameraView.addFrameProcessor(MainActivity.this);



        toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cameraFacing = (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) ? Facing.BACK : Facing.FRONT;
                faceDetectionCameraView.setFacing(cameraFacing);
            }
        });

        bottomSheetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    CropImage.activity().start(MainActivity.this);

            }
        });


        bottomSheetRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        bottomSheetRecyclerView.setAdapter(new FaceDetectionAdapter(faceDetectionModels, MainActivity.this));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri imageUri =  result.getUri();
                try {
                    analyseImage(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void analyseImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        faceDetectionModels.clear();

        Objects.requireNonNull(bottomSheetRecyclerView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

        showProgress();
        InputImage firebaseInputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);
        FaceDetectorOptions options =
                new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
                .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_ALL)
                .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_ALL)
                .build();

        FaceDetector faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(options);

        faceDetector.process(firebaseInputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Face> faces) {
                        Bitmap mutableImage = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                        detectFaces(faces, mutableImage);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableImage);
                        hideProgress();
                        bottomSheetRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        hideProgress();

                    }
                });

    }

    private void detectFaces(List<Face> faces, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(faces == null || bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint facePaint = new Paint();
        facePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        facePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        facePaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

        Paint faceTextPaint = new Paint();
        faceTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        faceTextPaint.setTextSize(30f);
        faceTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);


        Paint landmarkPaint = new Paint();
        landmarkPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        landmarkPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        landmarkPaint.setStrokeWidth(8f);

        for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
            canvas.drawRect(faces.get(i).getBoundingBox(), facePaint);
            canvas.drawText("Face" + i,
                    (faces.get(i).getBoundingBox().centerX()
                    -(faces.get(i).getBoundingBox().width() >> 1) + 8f),
                    (faces.get(i).getBoundingBox().centerY() + (faces.get(i).getBoundingBox().height() >> 1) - 8f), facePaint);

            Face face = faces.get(i); //get one face


            if(face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE) != null){
                FaceLandmark leftEye = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE);
                //Now we have our left eye, we draw a little circle
                canvas.drawCircle(leftEye.getPosition().x, leftEye.getPosition().y, 8f, landmarkPaint);
            }
            if(face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE) != null){
                FaceLandmark rightEye = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE);
                //Now we have our left eye, we draw a little circle
                canvas.drawCircle(rightEye.getPosition().x, rightEye.getPosition().y, 8f, landmarkPaint);
            }
            if(face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.NOSE_BASE) != null){
                FaceLandmark noseBase = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.NOSE_BASE);
                //Now we have our left eye, we draw a little circle
                canvas.drawCircle(noseBase.getPosition().x, noseBase.getPosition().y, 8f, landmarkPaint);
            }
            if(face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR) != null){
                FaceLandmark leftEar = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR);
                //Now we have our left eye, we draw a little circle
                canvas.drawCircle(leftEar.getPosition().x, leftEar.getPosition().y, 8f, landmarkPaint);
            }
            if(face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR) != null){
                FaceLandmark rightEar = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR);
                //Now we have our left eye, we draw a little circle
                canvas.drawCircle(rightEar.getPosition().x, rightEar.getPosition().y, 8f, landmarkPaint);
            }
            if(face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_LEFT) != null && face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_BOTTOM) != null && face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_RIGHT) != null){
                FaceLandmark mouthLeft = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_LEFT);
                FaceLandmark mouthRight = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_RIGHT);
                FaceLandmark mouthBottom = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_BOTTOM);
                //Now we have our left eye, we draw a little circle
                canvas.drawLine(mouthLeft.getPosition().x, mouthLeft.getPosition().y, mouthBottom.getPosition().x, mouthBottom.getPosition().y, landmarkPaint);
                canvas.drawLine(mouthBottom.getPosition().x, mouthBottom.getPosition().y, mouthRight.getPosition().x, mouthRight.getPosition().y, landmarkPaint);
            }

            faceDetectionModels.add(new FaceDetectionModel(i, "Smiling probability"
            + face.getSmilingProbability()));

            faceDetectionModels.add(new FaceDetectionModel(i, "Left eye open probability"
                    + face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability()));

            faceDetectionModels.add(new FaceDetectionModel(i, "Right eye open probability"
                    + face.getRightEyeOpenProbability()));



        }
    }

    private void showProgress() {
        findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_button_img).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_butotn_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideProgress() {
        findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_button_img).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_butotn_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //real-time detection starts HERE

    @Override
    public void process(@NonNull Frame frame) {
        //setting up width and frame height
        int width = frame.getSize().getWidth();
        int height = frame.getSize().getHeight();

        byte[] byteArray = frame.getData();
        InputImage image = InputImage.fromByteArray(
                //frame.getData()
                byteArray,
                width,
                height,
                //rotation
                (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) ? 90 : 270,
                //image format
                InputImage.IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12 // or IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12
        );

        //Contour mode all is real time contour detection
        FaceDetectorOptions realTimeOpts = new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                .build();

        FaceDetector faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(realTimeOpts);
        faceDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Face> faces) {

        //don't have image yet set to null first
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

        //bitmap stores pixels of image

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //canvas hold the draw calls -- write into the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        //paint specifies what the canvas should draw
        Paint dotPaint = new Paint();
        dotPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        dotPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        dotPaint.setStrokeWidth(6f);

        Paint linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

        for (Face face : faces) {


            //fetching contours
                List<PointF> faceContours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.FACE
                ).getPoints();

                for (int i = 0; i < faceContours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF faceContour = faceContours.get(i);
                    if (i != (faceContours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(
                                //if not at last index, continue drawing to next index
                                faceContour.x, faceContour.y, faceContours.get(i + 1).x, faceContours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint
                        );
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                    //always draw circle
                    canvas.drawCircle(faceContour.x, faceContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);
                }//end inner loop


                List<PointF> leftEyebrowTopCountours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.LEFT_EYEBROW_TOP).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < leftEyebrowTopCountours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF leftEyebrowTopContour = leftEyebrowTopCountours.get(i);
                    if (i != (leftEyebrowTopCountours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(leftEyebrowTopContour.x, leftEyebrowTopContour.y, leftEyebrowTopCountours.get(i + 1).x, leftEyebrowTopCountours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;
                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(leftEyebrowTopContour.x, leftEyebrowTopContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }

                List<PointF> rightEyebrowTopCountours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.RIGHT_EYEBROW_TOP).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < rightEyebrowTopCountours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF rightEyebrowContour = rightEyebrowTopCountours.get(i);
                    if (i != (rightEyebrowTopCountours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(rightEyebrowContour.x, rightEyebrowContour.y, rightEyebrowTopCountours.get(i + 1).x, rightEyebrowTopCountours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;

                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(rightEyebrowContour.x, rightEyebrowContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }

                List<PointF> rightEyebrowBottomCountours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.RIGHT_EYEBROW_BOTTOM).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < rightEyebrowBottomCountours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF rightEyebrowBottomContour = rightEyebrowBottomCountours.get(i);
                    if (i != (rightEyebrowBottomCountours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(rightEyebrowBottomContour.x, rightEyebrowBottomContour.y, rightEyebrowBottomCountours.get(i + 1).x, rightEyebrowBottomCountours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;
                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(rightEyebrowBottomContour.x, rightEyebrowBottomContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }

                List<PointF> leftEyeContours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.LEFT_EYE).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < leftEyeContours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF leftEyeContour = leftEyeContours.get(i);
                    if (i != (leftEyeContours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(leftEyeContour.x, leftEyeContour.y, leftEyeContours.get(i + 1).x, leftEyeContours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);

                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(leftEyeContour.x, leftEyeContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);


                }

                List<PointF> rightEyeContours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.RIGHT_EYE).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < rightEyeContours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF rightEyeContour = rightEyeContours.get(i);
                    if (i != (rightEyeContours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(rightEyeContour.x, rightEyeContour.y, rightEyeContours.get(i + 1).x, rightEyeContours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);

                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(rightEyeContour.x, rightEyeContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);


                }

                List<PointF> upperLipTopContour = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.UPPER_LIP_TOP).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < upperLipTopContour.size(); i++) {
                    PointF upperLipContour = upperLipTopContour.get(i);
                    if (i != (upperLipTopContour.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(upperLipContour.x, upperLipContour.y,
                                upperLipTopContour.get(i + 1).x,
                                upperLipTopContour.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;

                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(upperLipContour.x, upperLipContour.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }

                List<PointF> upperLipBottomContour = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < upperLipBottomContour.size(); i++) {
                    PointF upBottom = upperLipBottomContour.get(i);
                    if (i != (upperLipBottomContour.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(upBottom.x, upBottom.y, upperLipBottomContour.get(i + 1).x, upperLipBottomContour.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;

                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(upBottom.x, upBottom.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }
                List<PointF> lowerLipTopContour = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.LOWER_LIP_TOP).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < lowerLipTopContour.size(); i++) {
                    PointF lowerTop = lowerLipTopContour.get(i);
                    if (i != (lowerLipTopContour.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(lowerTop.x, lowerTop.y, lowerLipTopContour.get(i + 1).x, lowerLipTopContour.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }
                    else{
                        return;

                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(lowerTop.x, lowerTop.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }
                List<PointF> lowerLipBottomContour = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.LOWER_LIP_BOTTOM).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < lowerLipBottomContour.size(); i++) {
                    PointF lowerBottom = lowerLipBottomContour.get(i);
                    if (i != (lowerLipBottomContour.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(lowerBottom.x, lowerBottom.y, lowerLipBottomContour.get(i + 1).x, lowerLipBottomContour.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;
                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(lowerBottom.x, lowerBottom.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }

                List<PointF> noseBridgeContours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.NOSE_BRIDGE).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < noseBridgeContours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF noseBridge = noseBridgeContours.get(i);
                    if (i != (noseBridgeContours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(noseBridge.x, noseBridge.y, noseBridgeContours.get(i + 1).x, noseBridgeContours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;

                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(noseBridge.x, noseBridge.y, 4f, dotPaint);

                }

                List<PointF> noseBottomContours = face.getContour(
                        FaceContour.NOSE_BOTTOM).getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < noseBottomContours.size(); i++) {
                    PointF noseBottom = noseBottomContours.get(i);
                    if (i != (noseBottomContours.size() - 1)) {
                        canvas.drawLine(noseBottom.x, noseBottom.y, noseBottomContours.get(i + 1).x, noseBottomContours.get(i + 1).y, linePaint);
                    }else{
                        return;

                    }
                    canvas.drawCircle(noseBottom.x, noseBottom.y, 4f, dotPaint);


                    //facing front flip image
                    if (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) {
                        //Flip image!
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.preScale(-1f, 1f);
                        Bitmap flippedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                                matrix, true);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(flippedBitmap);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }


                }//end outer loop
                canvas.save();

        }
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure (@NonNull Exception e){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
            }


        });
    }




}
```

Edit: I am getting this error

```
Getting this error now: 2021-04-27 19:12:05.335 538-1065/system_process E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.RemoteException: Couldn't get ApplicationInfo for package android.frameworks.sensorservice@1.0::ISensorManager
    at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:2158)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1178)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Couldn't get ApplicationInfo for package android.frameworks.sensorservice@1.0::ISensorManager
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$PackageManagerNative.getTargetSdkVersionForPackage(PackageManagerService.java:23957)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManagerNative$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManagerNative.java:255)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi, the error I am getting is this: `2021-04-25 22:19:55.448 17489-19142/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1`, which I guess is because I'm using several bitmaps. However, I need those bitmaps for the flipped image, detecting features in a photo, and real time face detection. Any idea how I could possibly avoid this error? Thanks.

Comment: It is just a warning. Please post your full logcat with the question.

Comment: Hi, I don't have any error. My app isn't crashing, it's just the functionality for real-time face detection isn't working. Face detection for photos is working fine. Under error in logcat I found this: `2021-04-25 23:02:07.186 19552-19552/? E/sh.facedetecto: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-04-25 23:02:08.165 19552-19602/com.krish.facedetector E/EGL_emulation: eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2021-04-25 23:02:08.165 19552-19602/com.krish.facedetector E/EGL_emulation: tid 19602: eglQueryContext(1902): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)`

Comment: Also, I added that to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Please help. Someone.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Camera streaming output with MLKit, you can use the CameraX ImageAnalysis use case. It produces android.media.Image with YUV_420_888 format which can be directly converted to mlkit InputImage.

Alternatively, you can also use the CameraXSource library that ML Kit has just published. The sample code is [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/4645ec6011d5373283b31b79a12fd62f48af3c5f/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/CameraXSourceDemoActivity.java#L166). This eliminates the boilerplate code for you to set up camerax usecases and creates MLKit Inputs for you internally from the cameraX output. Note that this is still an beta SDK. We are looking forward to your feedback.

In order to use the API, you need to add the following dependency into your app:

implementation 'com.google.mlkit:camera:16.0.0-beta1'

Comment: Hi, I added the dependency, still not working. Thanks.

Comment: I put the new error in my original post. It seems like a thread error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429174/service-callback-throws-uncaught-remote-exception-exceptions-are-not-yet-supp. Not sure how to fix it though

Comment: Hi, you should not do any ui modification out of main thread. Could you instead use: myAcitity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Update your UI elements here
    }
});

Comment: Please be more specific. Which piece of code should I put in this? Thanks.